# Adding time values together to form a Total

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code, and am expecting the total to be 12:37:47 but I'm getting a whole number of 12 instead.  These are the results:

Category 1 - 06:02:06

Category 2 - 06:35:41

Total - 12

How can I get a Total result of 12:37:47?

```
$sql    = "SELECT hesk_categories.name, COALESCE(NULLIF(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TimeSpent))),0),'00:00:00') AS TimeSpent from hesk_categories left Join hesk_tickets on hesk_categories.id = hesk_tickets.category left join TimeSpent on hesk_tickets.id = TimeSpent.ID and (DateCreated between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() ) where hesk_categories.name <> 'Feature Request' group by hesk_categories.name";
$query  = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $TimeSpent = $row['TimeSpent'];
    $TimeSpent = $TimeSpent + $TimeSpent;

    $message.="<tr>";
    $message.="<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    $message.="<td>" . $row['TimeSpent'] . "</td>";
    $message.="<tr>";
}

$message.="<tr>";
$message.="<td>Total</td>";


    if ($TimeSpent >= '10:00:00')
    {
        $message.="<td><b><font color='red'>" . $TimeSpent . " (Support Hours have exceeded 10 hours for the month.)</font></b></td>";
    }
    else
    {
        $message.="<td>" . $TimeSpent . "</td>";
    }
$message.="</tr>";
$message.="</table><br>";
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$TimeSpent = $row['TimeSpent'];    $TimeSpent = $TimeSpent + $TimeSpent;`? Do you want to add time or add total of hours, mins, secs?

Comment: Yes, total time including hours, mins, secs

Comment: You would be better off getting the time from the database in number of seconds and then formatting the display in PHP (or fetching both).  Your code is trying to add 2 formatted times together as numbers (and it doesn't accumulate the total either).

Comment: You can not can not calculate hour, minutes that way simply.

Comment: Doing `if ($TimeSpent >= '10:00:00')` is kinda bad style. I think it might work, but you're not comparing dates, but strings, and you never know how that will turn out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the query:

```
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TimeSpent)) as TimeSpentSeconds
```

and this to the if statement:

```
if ($TimeSpentSeconds >= 36000)
{
    $TimeSpentSeconds = $TimeSpentSeconds / 3600;
    $message.="<td><b><font color='red'>" . number_format((float)$TimeSpentSeconds, 2, '.', '') . " hrs (Support Hours have exceeded 10 hours for the month.)</font></b></td>";
}
else
{
    $TimeSpentSeconds = $TimeSpentSeconds / 3600;
    $message.="<td>" . $number_format((float)$TimeSpentSeconds, 2, '.', '') . " hrs</td>";
}
```

Does the job.